# Failed a review audit by flagging a moderator because of a warning

Tags: support, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

I failed this review audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10042481

I got confused by the warning

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

in the post and I flagged the post for moderator help because I got confused. I assumed that something went wrong and that a moderator is in a better position to handle this post than me.

But it was a review audit. It's okay, a failed review audit does not hurt. Just saying.

I wonder if this audit should be removed because it's confusing. I also wonder whether I did the right thing: If I see something suspicious and think it's better handled by a moderator I can flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The salient point is:

**Don't flag a post just because there's a warning.**

Comment: Delightfully laconic :)

Answer (score 10):

That warning doesn't indicate that a post is spam, just that something about it tripped a "possible spam" heuristic. From what I've seen, a number of factors contribute to this, and you do get false positives.

The key part of that message is the last section: "please review carefully". That's all it's asking you to do. Examine the post a little more carefully than usual to see if anything about it appears spammy. If so, flag. If everything looks perfectly normal, review as you normally would.

I think this audit serves a useful purpose, because it helps educate people who flag good posts just because they see a warning. I've seen people try to game the system and work around audits by approving everything except posts that have some kind of warning on them. This catches that behavior.

Comment: Thanks. You nailed it with the last paragraph.

Answer (score 8):

There's nothing wrong with the audit.  It's doing its job perfectly.  Flagging a quality post that doesn't have any problems with it isn't an appropriate review action.

Comment: And the warning at the top of the post is not a problem?

Comment: @nalply Nope.  The warning was telling you to review carefully.  You didn't review carefully and instead took an inappropriate action.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought that the post was of good quality but I thought that the system made a mistake and flagged it for moderator help to perhaps fix the mistake.

Comment: @nalply It didn't flag it for moderator help, it indicated that an automated process found red flags to indicate it might be spam, but wants a human to double check it.  It's your job to see if the post is *actually* spam or a false positive.  This post isn't spam, and doesn't have other problems, so you should indicate as such from the queue.  If we were sufficiently confident in the automated processes to just delete the possible spam without human verification you wouldn't have seen the post in the first place.  (Which does actually happen for some posts.)

Answer (score 2):

Flagging a moderator isn't a viable option in this scenario.  Generally, you'd flag a moderator if the post can't be dealt with by yourself or through other existing mechanisms for post removal.

Here though...there's ***nothing*** wrong with the content.  In fact, I give you some credit since you did notice that there was the message that it was suspect.  But don't freak out about it.

Next time though, don't think that a moderator should be helping you with this.  Often times, the system does denote a post as low quality, so just be more thorough with your reviews.